# can we use some other dockerrun file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

by default ebs uses `Dockerrun.aws.json` file to deploy. we have a requirement to have multiple `dockerrun` files, like `Dockerrun.aws.json` and `Dockerrun-staging.aws.json`. 
Is it possible to make sure deployment uses `Dockerrun-Staging.aws.json` file instead of `Dockerrun.aws.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not find any documentation on how to provide target file on deploy. I ended up creating separate folders for staging and production then execute the eb deploy on the target environment folder

```
:docker-run$ tree
.
├── production
│   └── Dockerrun.aws.json
└── staging
    └── Dockerrun.aws.json
```

2 directories, 2 files